# Can I use jQuery to create a file (and its content) dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

Here is my HTML code,

```
<ul>
  <li> Download <a href="#">file1</a> </li>
  <li> Download <a href="#">file2</a> </li>
  <li> Download <a href="#">file3</a> </li>
</ul>
```

I want to create something like `"href=filename.txt"`.  The `"filename"` of the text file and its content needs to be created dynamically based on which  tag was clicked.

I use a web API to get data in JSON format and hence believe security should not be an issue.

Comment: Doing this server-side would make more sense. Is there any reason you've settled on JavaScript?

Comment: HTML4 does not allow any file operation in the client side because of security considerations. HTML5 has a File API which can do this.

Comment: Jquery is a JavaScript framework - it cannot do things JS cannot. Some browsers can read files but writing them is a security issue anywhere

Comment: The Question "question" and your question content, especially the code - do not match. You're asking about file creation, but in your demo you provided a "Download"-something HTML where you need to do exactly what??

Comment: Take a look at this: [SAVING GENERATED FILES ON THE CLIENT-SIDE](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/08/Saving-generated-files-on-the-client-side)

Comment: Thanks all for the quick help.

Comment: @KAUSHIKH.S., you better clarify your question to avoid getting it closed

Answer (score 26):

As of **HTML5**, you can use a combination of [`data:` URL](http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/single-page.html#data-protocol) and [`download` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/single-page.html#downloading-resources). For example,

```
<a href="data:text/plain;charset=UTF-8,Hello%20World!" download="filename.txt">Download</a>
```

Or, programatically,

```
<a id="programatically" href="#" download="date.txt">Download</a>
```

```
$("a#programatically").click(function() {
    var now = new Date().toString();
    this.href = "data:text/plain;charset=UTF-8," + encodeURIComponent(now);
});​
```

[**See it here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/enbMe/)

Unfortunately, [`download` attribute is not fully supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=download) and [`data:` URLs are in good track](http://caniuse.com/#feat=datauri).

Now, for a better cross-browser support you will need to create the file dynamically at server-side.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a [data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme), this is a very simple example:

```html
<html>
<body>
<a href="#">click</a>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").click(function() {
        window.location.href = "data:text/plain;charset=UTF-8,Hello World";
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

You cannot set the filename, however.